# Google App Engine - DatastoreFailureException: internal error

Tags: google-app-engine

My Application on Google App Engine has been running for almost a year now, and without any recent changes from me certainly it brings

DatastoreFailureException: internal error

from time to time on arbitrary datastore access operations. there is no downtime information and surprisingly no support from google (except you pay 150 a month)

so what could be the issue? can anybody help?

here is a full exception:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreFailureException: internal error.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:62)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$AsyncCallWrapper.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$5.getFutureWithOptionalTimeout(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:292)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$5.aggregate(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:264)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$5.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:235)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$5.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ResultAdapter.now(ResultAdapter.java:29)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round$1.now(LoadEngine.java:70)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round$1.now(LoadEngine.java:1)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round$2.now(LoadEngine.java:99)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ref.StdRef.get(StdRef.java:57)
    at net.dowalil.rtp.server.dao.WeltDAO.readFahrerById(WeltDAO.java:700)
    at net.dowalil.rtp.server.RtpResource.readQualifying(RtpResource.java:1321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a defect, I think that your best bet would be to star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11811&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log). Updates are usually sent from Google through their Public Issue Trackers.

Comment: Are you sure this is the same issue as mine? You access datastore when you do that?

Comment: I don't. I saw THAT public issue tracker. Looking at the error he does get  raise _ToDatastoreError(err), so I guess somewhere it hits the datastore